# MySQL search with 'group_concat' field and 'having' clause

Tags: mysql, sql, having

I have this query:

```
select
  departments.id as id,
  departments.active as active,
  departments.origin as origin,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR, origin, CURDATE()) as duration,
  CONCAT (departments.name, ' ', departments.section) as name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(persons.name SEPARATOR ', ') as persons,
  CONCAT (units.type, ' - ', units.name) as unit
from `departments`
  inner join `units` on `departments`.`unit_id` = `units`.`id`
  left join `department_person` on `departments`.`id` = `department_person`.`department_id`
  left join `persons` on `department_person`.`person_id` = `persons`.`id`
where ((departments.id like '%search%')
       or (CONCAT (departments.name, ' ', departments.section) like '%search%')
       or (TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR, origin, CURDATE()) like '%search%')
       or (CONCAT (units.type, ' - ', units.name) like '%search%')
       or (LOWER(`departments`.`active`) LIKE '%search%')
)
group by `departments`.`id`
having GROUP_CONCAT(persons.name SEPARATOR ', ') LIKE '%search%'
order by `id` asc
limit 10
offset 0
```

I want to perform a search within ALL the selected fields: id, active, origin, duration, name, unit and **persons**. 
Everything works fine except with when I add the `having GROUP_CONCAT(persons.name SEPARATOR ', ') LIKE '%search'` clause to search within persons. Then, nothing is returned...

Could you please tell me how to modify the query so that I can search within the persons, group_concat field also?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is so much wrong with the grouping here it's hard to start... In the mean time, just wrap the query with parentheses and put a `WHERE persons like...` after it

Comment: What do you mean with so much wrong, John? Perhaps the structure of the query is not pragmatically the best, but it is extracted from a plugin that a use for searching in data tables (through AJAX calls to the database) and should be kept as is... Please, could you be more explicit?

Comment: Why not adding the condition under where clause? e.g persons.name like '%search%'.

Comment: Because you group by the department id *only*, any other field that is not an aggregated field will be projected by randomly picking one among all the available in the group. In 99% of the cases, it is not what the programmer expects, so I encourage you to revise your query. Keep in mind this "feature" is relatively new and that with most of other engines, you'd get an immediate error as you should be grouping by *all* the selected columns but the aggregates.

Comment: What do you put in '%search%' string?
Can you write what you have usually as a result of GROUP_CONCAT(persons.name SEPARATOR ', ')?